# How to change directory and run further command in that directory using python?

Tags: python, subprocess

I want make my code to use a directory that is changed in the previous command: like cd /some/directory

1. I type cd `/some/directory` and type Enter , Now i am in /some/directory
2. Now when i type a command this should execute in `/some/directory`

How can I use the `/some/directory` for further command execution in python?

I try using `subprocess.run` and `os.system`, but still the code run separately..

Here is the code

```
import os

os.system(r"cd/ | cd \Project\Path | git status")
```

Comment: your question is not clear. what you are trying to say from step 1 to 4?

Comment: @Adiii I want to change the path/directory/location before run the real command. But when I use the code above, its run separately and the last command (git status) run at location where I place this code file, not at the location I wanted.

Comment: Oh got it. check my answer.

Comment: Ls will show the content to help you in debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `&&` instead pipe `|`. so, in this case, will `git status` will only work if `cd /some_directory` worked. `&&` means to execute the next command if the previous exited with status 0. Change the path according to your OS and directory.

> | : The pipe operator, it passes the output of one command as input to
>   another. A command built from the pipe operator is called a pipeline.

[what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators)

```
import os

os.system(r"cd /home/code/ && ls && git status")
```